# VBA Goalseek with Variable instead of Cell

Tags: vba, excel, variables

I need to use Goalseek in my VBA code, but rather than seeking a goal for a target "CELL" in my spreadsheet, I need to seek a goal for a "VARIABLE" within my VBA code.

e.g.
Rather than setting some target CELL to "A3", I need to set a target VARIABLE declared in my VBA code.

Same applies, of course, to the "By changing" field.

Is that even possible?

Comment: Do you mean that you are using VBA in Excel? Which version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a cell location that is off-screen to do the calculation, then once the process is finished, load the cell value into your variable, e.g.:

```
...GoalSeek ... ChangingCell:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells("A5000")
MyVar = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells("A5000").Value
```

Comment: Simple and crude way to do it, but does the job I guess. Thanks a lot Mellamokb.